# Azure DevOps Board Work Item created with large ID

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I've created a few Work Items in DevOps Boards.  They start at 1 and go up to 15.

Today I created a new Work Item and it was created with an ID of 624.

Why?  There are no other Work Items in between.  I tried changing the url of other work items and replaced with 624 and the result is:

```
Server error
TF401232: Work item 623 does not exist, or you do not have permissions to read it.
```

What is going on here?
How can I restart from ID 16?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is going on here? How can I restart from ID 16?

As we know, Workitem used for the organization level not the project level.

Therefore, the ID of the workitem is incremented by the workitem  in the entire set. You need to check if other items have workitem created in other team projects or they have been created and then deleted, you can find them in the recycle bin.

Since workitem is used for the entire set, to avoid duplicate IDs, it is not allowed to continue to use the ID of 16.

Comment: Thank you.  I was thinking something like that might be happening.  I will check with other projects to see if work items have been added.

Comment: @user19007114, So, how about the result after you check it? Does above answer help you?

Comment: Yes.  Another person had created another project (which I did not have access to), and migrated some issues from another system.  Thanks :)